# Does Waldhausen K-theory detect homotopy type?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Recall that $A(X)$, the K-theory of a connected, pointed space X, is defined as the K-theory spectrum of the ring spectrum $\Sigma^\infty_+ \Omega X$ (or via a plethora of alternative definitions). Is it known if the homotopy type of $A(X)$ determines the homotopy type of $X$? If not, what is the best one can hope for?

Of course, since $X$ is connected the space $\Omega X$ with its loop space structure determines the homotopy type of $X$, but I am not sure if this is still true when we take $\Sigma^\infty_+$,  I am worried we get might get $X$ only up to $\Sigma^n \Omega^n $. Then there is the question of if ring spectra of this type can have the same K-theory, perhaps we should assume $X$ simply connected to get a positive answer?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are simply connected, a map $f:\:X\to Y$ is an equivalence if and only if $A(f)$ is an equivalence. This is the kind of tool Goodwillie calculus is for. Among other things, it describes the first homotopy group on which $A(f)$ is not an iso in terms of the first $f$ is not. If the map is an iso on fundamental group, it tells you something, but I don't remember what; probably it doesn't reflect equivalences.

Comment: I'm still not quite clear on what the question is -- are you asking (1) whether any map $X \to Y$ inducing an equivalence $A(X) \to A(Y)$ must be an equivalence, or (2) whether the abstract existence of an equivalence of spectra $A(X) \simeq A(Y)$ implies the existence of an equivalence $X \simeq Y$, or (3) same as (2), but assuming the equivalence $A(X) \simeq A(Y)$ is an equivalence of ring spectra? If (3), how "structured" do you want to assume the equivalence of ring spectra is --e.g. an equivalence of homotopy ring spectra, equivalence of $A_\infty$ ring spectra, etc?

Comment: @TimCampion Certainly what I would like most is conditions under which an equivalence $A(X) \simeq A(Y)$, as structured as needed, implies $X \simeq Y$.

Comment: @BenWieland can you say a few more words about your comment or point me towards a reference where Goodwillie calculus shows something similar?

Comment: @AndresMejia if $X\to Y$ is an $n$-equivalence, then $\Omega X\to \Omega Y$ is an $n-1$-equivalence, then $Q\Omega X\to Q\Omega Y$ is an $n-1$-equivalence, then $BGL_m(S[\Omega X])\to BGL_m(S[\Omega Y])$ is an $n$-equivalence, then pass to $K$-theory using the group completion theorem, which is tricky, but the trickiness is all in the discrete ring. I think Waldhausen already writes about stabilizing $K$-theory, whereas calculus generalizes this linear argument to quadratic, etc. See Dundas-McCarthy 1994

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answer to the question

> Does the homotopy type of $()$ determine the homotopy type of $$?

is No in general. As you say, $A(X)$ is determined by the homotopy type of $\Sigma^\infty \Omega X_+$ as an associative (or $A_\infty$) ring spectrum, and this ring spectrum does not uniquely determine $X$, even if $X$ is simply-connected.

For example, suppose $Z$ is a pointed space. Let $T(Z)$ be the free associative $S$-algebra generated by $Z$. I.e.,
$$T(Z)=\Sigma^\infty S^0\vee \Sigma^\infty Z \vee (\Sigma^\infty Z)^{\wedge 2} \vee \cdots .$$

If $Z$ is connected, there is an equivalence of associative ring spectra
$$ T(Z) \simeq \Sigma^\infty \Omega\Sigma Z_+.$$
The equivalence is a version of the classical James splitting. It is induced by a map of spectra $\Sigma^\infty Z \to \Sigma^\infty \Omega\Sigma Z_+$, extended to a map of ring spectra $T(Z)\to \Sigma^\infty \Omega\Sigma Z_+$ using freeness.

It follows that if $X$ and $Y$ are connected spaces such that $\Sigma X$ and $\Sigma Y$ are not equivalent, but $\Sigma^\infty X$ and $\Sigma^\infty Y$ are equivalent, then there is an equivalence $A(\Sigma X)\simeq A(\Sigma Y)$ providing a counterexample.

A couple of comments:

- It is well-known that there exist non-isomorphic groups $G$ and $H$ such that the group rings $\mathbb Z[G]$ and $\mathbb Z[H]$ are isomorphic. There are even examples with finite $G$ and $H$. One may wonder if for some of these examples the spherical group rings $\Sigma^\infty G_+$ and $\Sigma^\infty H_+$ are equivalent as associative ring spectra. If yes, then $BG$ and $BH$ would provide another counterexample.
- In general one can have non-equivalent ring spectra that have equivalent $K$-theories. For example, I believe that if $P$ and $Q$ are Morita equivalent in a suitable sense, then $K(P)\simeq K(Q)$. Can there be two spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that $\Sigma^\infty \Omega X_+$ and $\Sigma^\infty \Omega Y_+$ are not equivalent as ring spectra, but have equivalent categories of modules (in a strong enough sense to induce equivalence of $K$-theories)? It seems far fetched, but I don't know how to exclude this possibility. **Added later**: [A paper by Roggenkamp and Zimmerman](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271593/1-s2.0-S0022404900X00230/1-s2.0-002240499500121C/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEIP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQDPvFmhYCSH3uV39DkXovveN%2BOyDaQDB6Z%2F1kR3sS000gIgWfYmxwaYC3yWTlyGjTWWxBqI584z8DzOVDzIJUJcaEkqgwQI6%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAEGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDBSq2vFuLcecgiZDLirXAxDdL61ZrE4CZZcDfZvm6EeIjuIa1QUcLQpVO%2FnmGP4LboOLwHrmdToaRfYdRJsZKz1HYhCQ7vIcxrVZs7qfObCO9tCadIM8ROh1oIDyhbLkNRW3C6qwBnGQkOKTVGv9DLNCbszGXpbIDGk3%2FcPbPjo1n61XEGdjxcghedRSvYRAB2RRiGxX3ztHT42JLHZ0OJQPE2Wajhu7lI%2FYZeaLOXrZpKtTEVxUuaYa5CkHYaGJz590AaiAU1ayM%2FfrxjmJ%2FW9Xl2ninYRjDhz6Um7DTQPL1jL4Jr10gmSW6Sq9nWJSIhTKrN7GW49zKpJ%2BoVdD0ADeQB2DoE9Wh%2BgrEU%2BTZUKSRiDTRG8Hb7dy5dQO5Q4WsGqBGqkkrsmhU9u2vA6gVrKmhhkoeGA5PZZcHH32%2FWJJJr8K4IAfoDsqlZ21ycgEbb%2BncWPh9a8bGWLrU9i31vorMCaCvXtd21IEs8E8LX7qGXfZIs1L58ujJf8%2F0PyC8L%2FtxP%2FxB1DbgfxQU%2FJGAMuAdzTZ1mwxuBjgkPOSGmrerMyaOl8PyDWLlQghHOcOjHwRvNApCWmBM6SndIApBMoGaja16zQCUuZj4dvw9R8yyNt8Nt6JcK2eVai65y29JERsXqr3GDD7utuKBjqlAevKM%2Budwrs6ydAxjMs72xYyZttDS0qr4tyI0u7b8Pldqv2v1MqbxlbogF1m7Fj%2FoPhQ0r8QbHfCYP1YHGBCZzMiBzHUIGKWQT2bkVevTkSWhdueB80ZcVAVe5rIWd8%2FBHBu1jRpHOXi2uJQRWO3lFHkHnQvVpoE%2BrMvSS9%2Fut%2B75YFa31jvvM30fN5p68pVEeUP%2F84Bc0gHIiiXiiI8gfEs35g%2BKg%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20211001T102935Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYYFQ4EQ6V%2F20211001%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=24c11fc3ebd73feb971192d31deb20e90feac3f06e41b8a1184a48754f9c0a91&hash=44d93e5ecbbfbf4421a06fd1b82235a6df599e452d5f327646c6c2b115f5f87d&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=002240499500121C&tid=spdf-f84bc980-2baf-4830-a450-6a9fdfd04fa3&sid=912d2868500e4540d55b51c-0b6669052cf9gxrqb&type=client) gives an example of two groups $G$ and $H$ for which the rings $\mathbb Z[G]$ and $\mathbb Z[H]$ are not isomorphic, but Morita equivalent. It follows that the Quillen $K$-theory of these rings is isomorphic. One may ask whether the $K$-theory spectra of $\Sigma^\infty G_+$ and $\Sigma^\infty H_+$ are equivalent as well.

Comment: I am a bit confused at one point in your argument. It seems to me that the question concerns the ring spectrum $\Sigma^\infty(\Omega \Sigma X \amalg \{\ast\})$. That is, the ring structure is associated to the _disconnected_ space $(\Omega \Sigma X)_+$. So I don't understand where the James splitting comes in -- in the James splitting, the multiplication comes from the _connected_ space $\Omega \Sigma X$, and the unit of the algebra comes from a basepoint on $X$. (right?)

Comment: Notice that there is a natural equivalence of functors from pointed spaces to spectra $\Sigma^\infty Z_+\simeq \Sigma^\infty Z\vee S^0$. It follows that a stable splitting of $\Sigma^\infty \Omega\Sigma X$ extends easily to a stable splitting of $\Sigma^\infty \Omega\Sigma X_+\simeq \Sigma^\infty (\Omega \Sigma X)\vee S^0$. The natural map $\Sigma^\infty Z\to \Sigma^\infty \Omega\Sigma Z_+$ in my answer depends on a map $\Sigma^\infty \Omega\Sigma Z\to \Sigma^\infty (\Omega \Sigma Z) \vee S^0\xrightarrow{\simeq} \Sigma^\infty \Omega\Sigma Z_+$. Notice that this map exists only stably.

Comment: Yeah, I agree (I'm slowly becoming less confused.) The map going the other way is induced by the universal property of $\Omega \Sigma X$ as the free $E_1$-space on the $E_0$-space $X$, which is preserved by the symmetric monoidal left adjoint $\Sigma^\infty_+$. The indeterminacy in choice of map is matched here -- it again depends on a choice of splitting. I think I'm convinced enough that it's time for yet another comb through my own answer... my conclusion does indeed sound too strong, but what the heck did I do wrong...

Comment: @GregoryArone  Greg: if one could deduce from $\mathbb Z[G] = \mathbb Z[H]$ that $\Sigma^{\infty}G_+ = \Sigma^{\infty} H_+$ as $A_{\infty}$ ring spectra, one could conclude that the suspension spectra of $BG$ and $BH$ are equivalent, and then (from Nishida's observation) that they have the same $p$-Sylow subgroups, and thus have reproved a major theorem of Rogencamp and Scott.  Thus I am dubious about this first step!

Comment: @NicholasKuhn Nick, I was not suggesting that there should be a general implication of this kind. Just wondering if there exist two non-isomorphic discrete groups whose suspension spectra are equivalent as $A_\infty$-ring spectra. One could call this "the spherical group ring isomorphism problem". It does not look like anyone considered this question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I think $M,M'$ h-cobordant but not homotopy equivalent probably also give counter examples?

Comment: h-cobordant manifolds are homotopy equivalent. Perhaps you meant to say something else?

Comment: @archipelago Of course you are right, I got caught up in the description of K-theory using stable h-cobordism spaces and thought I was saying something nontrivial.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't get at $A$-theory specifically, but it seems to be already interesting to ask to what extent we can recover $X$ from knowing $\Sigma^\infty_+ \Omega X$. I believe that very often we can -- but take what I say with a grain of salt -- this is not my area of expertise:

**EDIT:** The following is wrong, as Gregory Arone's answer shows. Thanks to Maxime Ramzi for pointing out the error in the comments below. I will leave this up for the time being and possibly try to salvage some sort of positive statement later.

**Claim 1:** Let $X,Y$ be connected spaces. Suppose that $\Sigma^\infty_+ \Omega X \simeq \Sigma^\infty_+ \Omega Y$ as $A_\infty$ ring spectra. Then $X \simeq Y$.

**Proof:** Suppose that $\Sigma^\infty_+ \Omega X \simeq \Sigma^\infty_+ \Omega Y$ as $A_\infty$ ring spectra. Then we have an equivalence of module categories $Mod(\Sigma^\infty_+ \Omega X) \simeq Mod(\Sigma^\infty_+ \Omega Y)$ preserving the unit (the module category is not monoidal, but it does have a unit!). In other words, we have an equivalence of functor categories $Spectra^X \simeq Spectra^Y$ which preserves the representables. Preserving the representables amounts to saying that the equivalence commutes with the forgetful / evaluation functor to $Spectra$. This implies that the equivalence $Spectra^X \simeq Spectra^Y$ carries the comonad $\Sigma^\infty_X \Omega^\infty_X$ to the comonad $\Sigma^\infty_Y \Omega^\infty_Y$. The preservation of the unit also means that the equivalence preserves connectivities, so that we have an equivalence $(Spectra_{\geq 2}^X, \Sigma^\infty_X \Omega^\infty_X) \simeq (Spectra_{\geq 2}^Y, \Sigma^\infty_Y \Omega^\infty_Y)$, and so also an induced equivalence of categories of comonads. By a theorem of [Blomquist and Harper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.04157), the $\Sigma^\infty \dashv \Omega^\infty$ adjunction is comonadic after restricting to the simply-connected case. We may apply this fact levelwise to conclude that we have an equivalence $Spaces_{\ast,\geq 2}^X \simeq Spaces_{\ast,\geq 2}^Y$ of categories of functors valued in pointed, simply-connected spaces, which preserves the representables. By Lemma 2 below, this implies that $\overline{X^+} \simeq \overline{Y^+}$, where $X^+$ is the $\infty$-category $X$ with a zero object added and $\overline C$ is the completion of $C$ under splitting of idempotents. But as $X$ is an $\infty$-groupoid, it is clear that there are no nontrivial idempotents in $X^+$, and similarly for $Y$. So $X^+ \simeq Y^+$. As the equivalence preserves the representables, we must have $X \simeq Y$.

**Lemma 2:** For any $\infty$-category $C$ enriched in $Spaces_{\ast,\geq 2}$, define $\overline{C^+}$ to be $C$ with a zero object added and idempotents split. Then if $C,D$ are two such $\infty$-categories, we have an equivalence $Spaces_{\ast,\geq 2}^C \simeq Spaces_{\ast,\geq 2}^D$ of $Spaces_{\ast,\geq 2}$-enriched categories of $Spaces_{\ast,\geq 2}$-enriched functor categories to $Spaces_{\ast,\geq 2}$ if and only if $\overline{C^+} \simeq \overline{D^+}$.

**Proof:** When $Spaces_{\ast,\geq 2}$ is replaced by $Spaces_\ast$, this is well-known, an application of the theory of [Cauchy completion](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cauchy+complete+category) in enriched category theory. The same argument works in this case.

Comment: Our answers appear to contradict each other. Is mine wrong?

Comment: @GregoryArone Presumably mine is the one that's wrong...

Comment: How does preserving the forgetful functor to Spectra imply preserving the comonad in an adjunction with Spaces^X (resp.  Spaces^Y) ?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi What I'm claiming there is that $\Sigma^\infty_X \dashv \Omega^\infty_X$ is given by taking $\Sigma^\infty \dashv \Omega^\infty$ pointwise in $x \in X$. After all, the zero object, limits, and colimits are all defined pointwise in this functor category. So loops and suspension are as well. Actually, suspension is irrelevant: because loops are defined pointwise, $\Omega^\infty_X$ is defined pointwise, and so its left adjoint must agree with the the left adjoint you construct by applying $\Sigma^\infty$ pointwise. I agree that felt like the most surprising point in the argument, but

Comment: Yes, but "pointwise" just means "if you forget after, you could have forgotten before". I don't think this shows that the adjunction is the same, or at least it deserves some clarification. I think this is where it's all happening: I am absolutely ready to believe that the same statement with spaces is completely true (and I'm not even sure you need a preservation of units in this case, you can e.g. easily extract the free loop space on X from spaces^X), so I think this is the crux of the argument

Comment: and I think this is what should be explained in more care : stated as such it's missing something

Comment: @MaximeRamzi You're totally right, thanks! I might come back to this later. Blomquist and Harper show that even $H \mathbb Z \wedge \Sigma^\infty \Omega^\infty$ is comonadic in the pointed, simply-connected case. It's hard for me to imagine too many comonads on chain complexes that do the same thing on homology groups, so there might be something to say here (it would have to involve restrictions on $X$ and $Y$ of course...)

Comment: Mhm but if the argument works with $\mathbb Z$ then something else is definitely wrong: Gregory's point that there are non isomorphic groups with $\mathbb Z[G]\cong \mathbb Z[H]$ still stands, so certainly no argument that only requires "$Mod_\mathbb Z^{BG}\simeq Mod_{\mathbb Z}^{BH}$ + preservation of units" can work

Comment: presumably if something like this were to hold, it would be because the sphere has more information than $\mathbb Z$ - see Gregory's questions at the end of his answers (by the way, if someone knows answer to these, I'm interested !)